# Comparing multiple files and printing larger values along with filenames

Tags: shell-script, file-comparison, numeric-data

I have about 2000 files in the following format:

FILEA: WHWH-19975612.txt

```
0.1   70  30
0.01  70  32
0.9   72  32
...
```

FILEB: WHWH-20004526.txt

```
0.2   70 30
0.001 70 32
1.0   72 32
...
```

Desired output

```
0.2  70 30  WHWH-20004526
0.01 70 32  WHWH-19975612
1.0  72 32  WHWH-20004526
...
```

Doing this will keep track of files where larger values are present, which I can call for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of files fits into one call to `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '{ if ($1 > maxvalues[$2" "$3]) { 
         maxvalues[$2" "$3]=$1; 
         maxfiles[$2" "$3]=FILENAME; 
       }
     } 
     END { 
       for (i in maxvalues) printf "%-4s %5s %s\n", maxvalues[i], i, maxfiles[i] 
    }' \
    *
```

I created a test set of files with your sample data, and then by running:

```
for((i=20004527;i<20006526;i++))
do 
  cp WHWH-20004526.txt WHWH-${i}.txt
done
```

... to create ~2000 data files to work with.